# Remove "Open in Terminal" entries in Directory Menu panel plugin

Tags: xfce, panel

The Xfce panel plugin [Directory Menu](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/directorymenu) shows an entry "Open in terminal" for each directory.

[image: Xfce panel plugin "Directory Menu" shows "Open in terminal" entries for each directory]

Is it possible to remove these entries for all directories?